pip install pyqt5 stay blocked
I on a macbook pro M1max with the latest OS update, using VMwareFusion, the OS on the VM is kali linux (debian) with the latest update and upgrades.
I am using python3 in a venv environnement.
I am in need of downloading the pandasgui library which requires, pyqt5. But when the moments come to download it it get stuck here.
pip3 install pyqt5
Collecting pyqt5
  Using cached PyQt5-5.15.11.tar.gz (3.2 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... done
  Getting requirements to build wheel ... done
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml) ... -


and either never end of just timeout.
any ideas as to what might cause this ?
Well I was expecting a pip install to be easy and just have my library downloaded.

I am using python3 please what specific version of Python3?
